# Asp.Net Core 3 Identity - Custom Claims not present in JWT from browser

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

**Asp.Net Core 3.0**
I am using the `ASP.NET Core web application with Angular and Authentication` (Individual User Accounts) template (from Visual Studio 2019).
My intention is to add some Custom Claims in the generated `JWT` and use them in browser.
In order to do that, I have extended the `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`

```
public class MyCustomClaimsInjector : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyCustomClaimsFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var id = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("my_claim1", "AdditionalClaim1"));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("my_claim2", "AdditionalClaim2"));
        return id;
    }
}
```

As well, I have registered the extension in the `Startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyCustomClaimsFactory>();


        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }
```

During Sign In phase, started from the SPA client, the debugger passes through `MyCustomClaimsFactory` and adds the claims to the `ClaimsIdentity` in the `GenerateClaimsAsync` method.

But, I find strange why the JWT received in browser does not contain the Claims added by the `MyCustomClaimsFactory`.

Is my expectation to see the Custom Claim in the JWT in browser OK ?

Can anyone suggest the direction to dig in... Why the claims isn't present in the JWT ?

Decoded JWT is:
[image]

The SPA app:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Will share my results. Hope that will help anyone else.

I have implemented `IProfileService` and piped the `.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()`implementation in `ConfigureServices`.

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {         
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("my_FirstName", "user_FirstName"),
            new Claim("my_LastName", "user_LastName")
        };

        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {            
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        context.IsActive = (user != null);
    }
}
```

the Startup.cs file

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

With that, **now the JWT contains my custom claims**.
I am not sure why the override for `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` was not able to solve that.
Will try to study deeper those areas.

Comment: Did you continue to investigate why setting the claims with UserClaimsPrincipalFactory does not work?

I encountered the same problem today.

Comment: Started a chat in the gitter asp channel but didn't catch something usefull. The docs are so raw, that I considered to wait few months, hopin' minor releases will add as well some more details.I plan to update the answer once will discover the real reason.

Comment: Did you find out why the UserClaimsPrincipaFactory did not work? I noticed this approach works, however, it does not include the other default claims added before like username and preferred_name

Answer (score 3):

So today I encountered the same problem. I haven't used IdentityServer before so I'm not totally sure if the following is the correct way of doing it, but it is certainly easier than creating your own IProfileService implementation.

The default profile service calls

```
context.AddRequestedClaims(principal.Claims);
```

The requested claims are defined on the IdentityServer ApiResource that you are accessing. This ApiResource configuration is created by calling

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

This creates a default ApiResource configuration with the name "{Environment.ApplicationName}API".
This object also holds a collection of claim types to include when generating the JWT.

I couldn't find any documentation on whether this could also be set in the appsettings.json, but you can access it in the startup code.

TLDR; Change your startup code to something similar to this:

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = environment;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

    // ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<User, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // The options.ApiResources collection is automatically populated
                // by services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
                var apiResource = options.ApiResources[$"{Environment.ApplicationName}API"];
                // Example: add the user's roles to the token
                apiResource.UserClaims.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
                // Example: add another custom claim type
                apiResource.UserClaims.Add("CustomClaimName");
            });

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of some different claim types you've added? Sorry I don't quite understand where the ApiResource object lives?

Comment: I added comments and an example using a real claim type to the code, which should hopefully make it clearer. The ApiResource is a configuration object in the "options.ApiResources" collection that gets created automatically. You can read more about it in the documentation: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/api_resource.html

Comment: It seems I was wrong on where the default ApiResource configuration is created; I updated the code and the information should hopefully be correct now.